# Android and AppEngine web service: Json... RPC, REST... protocol buffers?

Tags: java, android, json, rest, protocol-buffers

I'm working on a web service that will be accessed from an Android app.  After doing some research on what's the best technology, I'm left somewhat confused and dazed by the options.

Obviously on the Android end I want it to be as lightweight as possible.  I also would prefer to share the common code since both are java, although that's less important.  My primary concern is having it be efficient, and after that, simple and elegant code.

I've tried gson on the Android end, and it works nicely. But then I read about protocol buffers, and that seems even more efficient, I'm not sure if it's a significant difference.  Also I'm not sure whether to go for RPC or REST.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the efficiency front, Protocol Buffers will probably be more efficient than any JSON implementation, thought not necessarily by as much as you think.  GSON is not particularly fast, but the Jackson library can almost compete with most binary serializers (Jackson is 2-4x faster than GSON in most situations and 10-20x faster on UTF-8 because it has special code for UTF-8).

But I'd still take Protocol Buffers over any JSON library because of the programming model.  With most JSON libraries, your have to check the structure of a message manually.  With Protocol Buffers, you specify message structures declaratively and the library will take care of the structural validation for you (though there will still be things that you need to validate manually).

Other libraries like Protocol Buffers: Apache Avro, Apache Thrift.

The Protostuff library uses the Protocol Buffers data model (so you get structural validation for free) but support serializing to JSON and YAML in addition to other formats.  This can be useful if you want your service to be consumed by Javascript code, where JSON is often the easiest thing to deal with.

Comment: Thanks for this info, that is what I suspected, but I found few things out there on google about using protocol buffers.  It would be nice if there were more examples out there on using protocol buffers.

Comment: The Protostuff lib looks awesome.  I didn't know of it, good tip!